# How to prevent child from firing parents tap event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a grid inside which i have a HyperLinkButton. The grid is subscribed to tap event.
this tap is also fired along with HyperLinkButton click event, which is not what i want. how can prevent the tap event to fire when HyperLinkButton is clicked.

```
<Grid Tap="grid_tap">
  <HyperLinkButton Click="hlb_click"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the event to be triggered in the Grid, you need to use the `Tap` event in the HyperLinkButton instead of `Click`.

```
<Grid Tap="grid_tap">
  <HyperLinkButton Tap="hlb_tap"/>
</Grid>
```

Then in the event handler, set the `e.Handled` property to prevent the event from bubbling up:

```
private void hlb_tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    // Your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I will try that in few hours and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

In the `hlb_click` event handler put this line:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: I am getting this error "System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Handled' and no extension method 'Handled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Also hyperLinkButton is in a UserControl that i am adding as a child in the Grid.

Comment: That's really odd. I can see Handled property in this page as well, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx